# Shiny: passing reactive value to function and re-evalute function if reactive value changes

Tags: r, shiny

I built a shiny dashboard, which takes an input file (as reactive) and creates some plots based on that file. As I did not want to rewrite all the code for barplots, histograms etc again and again, I created different functions for plotting bars, histograms etc.

As an input these functions take processed data. Usually that means that I take my raw data (stored in an reactive variable), manipulate some values and create some kind of cross tabulated dataframe, which is passed to the plotting function.

Everything works fine, except that the plots are not updated, if I change my input data. The reason for that seems to be that I first process my reactive data and then pass it to my function. Apparently one has to use the reactive variable in direct context with/inside the plot function to make the plot reactive too.

Before I start re-writing my dashboard (an option that I really don't like), I wanted to ask if somebody knew an easy workaround to pass processed reactive variables to functions and still re-evaluate these functions, if the reactive value changes?

As my code works, there is no need for a minimal example, but to make it easier to understand my problem, here is some kind of pseudo code

```
# read selected xlsx file
dat <- shiny::reactive({
    readxl::read_xlsx(path=input$selected_file$datapath)
})

# function to plot data
plot_bar <- function(dat,
                     .x,
                     .y){

    # plot data
    plot(data=dat,x=.x,y=.y)
}

# call plot_bar
plot_bar(dat=dat() %>% 
             dplyr::count(age),
         .x=age,
         .y=n)
```

As Ronak Shah mentioned I might have been a bit too lazy not sharing a reproducible example. Sorry for that. I was hoping that plain text would do the trick as it's hard to keep it minimal with dashboards :D

Anyways, here is some reproducible code. I hope this helps to clearify the problem.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("blupp"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput(inputId="sel_tibble",
                        label="select tibble",
                        choices=c("test1","test2"))
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            column(width=4,
                   plotOutput(outputId="barplot1")),
            column(width=4,
                   plotOutput(outputId="barplot2")),
            column(width=4,
                   plotOutput(outputId="barplot3"))
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram 
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    # some data
    dat_list <- list(test1=dplyr::tibble(X=1:10,
                                         Y=10:1,
                                         GRP1=sample(LETTERS[1:2],
                                                    size=10,
                                                    replace=T),
                                         GRP2=sample(LETTERS[5:6],
                                                     size=10,
                                                     replace=T)),
                     test2=dplyr::tibble(X=101:1000,
                                         Y=1000:101,
                                         GRP1=sample(LETTERS[1:2],
                                                    size=900,
                                                    replace=T),
                                         GRP2=sample(LETTERS[5:6],
                                                    size=900,
                                                    replace=T)))
    # Reactive: change between datasets (should affect plots)
    dat <- reactive({
        input$sel_tibble
        res <- dat_list[[input$sel_tibble]]
        return(res)
    })
    
    # Functions
    
    # passing processed reactive (plot won't change)
    plot_bar1 <- function(dat,
                         .x,
                         .y,
                         id){
        # NSE
        .x <- rlang::enquo(.x)
        .y <- rlang::enquo(.y)
        
        # Plot Date
        output[[id]] <- renderPlot({
            dat %>%
                ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x=!!.x,y=!!.y)) +
                ggplot2::geom_col()
        })
    }
    
    # passing reactive and processing inside function (plot changes)
    plot_bar2 <- function(dat,
                          .x,
                          id){
        # NSE
        .x <- rlang::enquo(.x)
        
        # Plot Date
        output[[id]] <- renderPlot({
            dat() %>%
                dplyr::count(!!.x) %>%
                ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x=!!.x,y=n)) +
                ggplot2::geom_col()
        })
    }
    
    # Output
    plot_bar1(dat=dat() %>%
                 dplyr::count(GRP1),
             .x=GRP1,
             .y=n,
             id="barplot1")
    
    plot_bar1(dat=dat() %>%
                 dplyr::count(GRP2),
             .x=GRP2,
             .y=n,
             id="barplot2")
    plot_bar2(dat=dat,
              .x=GRP1,
              id="barplot3")
    
    
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Can you provide `ui` and `server` code required for the question to be completely reproducible along with necessary data if required?

Comment: I added reproducible code and hope that helps to better understand my problem (still I think downvoting seems a little harsh as there is not really a problem with my code. My question is more related to the overall concept of reactive variables in action. But I guess there is enough room for different opinions on that topic :D)

Comment: Yes, probably. Not my downvote though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your way of program in shiny is wrong, but for me is odd having functions creating output values directly, and specially having functions defined in the server block. Also try to use different names for the data structures you're working with and the reactive functions you create.

I modified your code with my own practices and it works as you expected.

My advise, keep the outputs defined by name nor dynamically named, your functions best declared outside server function,  and if you need to add objects dynamically use removeUI and insertUI on your server code.

Working code

```
    library(shiny)
    
    # Define UI for application that draws a histogram
    ui <- fluidPage(
      
      # Application title
      titlePanel("blupp"),
      
      # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput(inputId="sel_tibble",
                      label="select tibble",
                      choices=c("test1","test2"))
        ),
        
        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
          column(width=4,
                 plotOutput(outputId="barplot1")),
          column(width=4,
                 plotOutput(outputId="barplot2")),
          column(width=4,
                 plotOutput(outputId="barplot3"))
        )
      )
    )
    
    dat_list <- list(test1=dplyr::tibble(X=1:10,
                                         Y=10:1,
                                         GRP1=sample(LETTERS[1:2],
                                                     size=10,
                                                     replace=T),
                                         GRP2=sample(LETTERS[5:6],
                                                     size=10,
                                                     replace=T)),
                     test2=dplyr::tibble(X=101:1000,
                                         Y=1000:101,
                                         GRP1=sample(LETTERS[1:2],
                                                     size=900,
                                                     replace=T),
                                         GRP2=sample(LETTERS[5:6],
                                                     size=900,
                                                     replace=T)))
    # Define server logic required to draw a histogram 
    
    
    plot_bar1 <- function(dat,
                          .x,
                          .y,
                          id){
      # NSE
      .x <- rlang::enquo(.x)
      .y <- rlang::enquo(.y)
      
      # Plot Date
      return(
        dat %>%
          ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x=!!.x,y=!!.y)) +
          ggplot2::geom_col()
      )
    }
    
    plot_bar2 <- function(dat,
                          .x,
                          id){
      # NSE
      .x <- rlang::enquo(.x)
      
      # Plot Date
      return(
        dat %>%
          dplyr::count(!!.x) %>%
          ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x=!!.x,y=n)) +
          ggplot2::geom_col()
      )
    }
    server <- function(input, output) {
      
      # some data
      
      # Reactive: change between datasets (should affect plots)
      dat <- reactive({
        #input$sel_tibble
        res <- dat_list[[input$sel_tibble]]
        print("data updated")
        return(res)
      })
      
      # Functions
      
      # passing processed reactive (plot won't change)
      
      output$barplot1 <- renderPlot({ 
        plot_bar1(dat=dat() %>%
                    dplyr::count(GRP1),
                  .x=GRP1,
                  .y=n,
                  id="barplot1") })
      output$barplot2 <- renderPlot({
        plot_bar1(dat=dat() %>%
                    dplyr::count(GRP2),
                  .x=GRP2,
                  .y=n,
                  id="barplot2")
      })
      output$barplot3 <- renderPlot({
        
        plot_bar2(dat=dat(),
                  .x=GRP1,
                  id="barplot3")
      })
      
      # passing reactive and processing inside function (plot changes)
      
    }
    
    # Output
    
    
    
    
    
    
    }
    
    # Run the application 
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Usually I define my functions outside the server function (in extra modules). I just tried to simplify everything here. Creating the output variables inside the functions seemd to be a good idea at the beginning as it keeps the server part pretty clean and easy to read and as it standardizes the few blocks the whole dashboard consists of. It's interesting to know that putting the outputvariables outside of my functions ensures reactivity. Still I am not 100 % sure why creating output inside the function stops reactivity ...

Comment: I don`t understand fully the entire shiny part,  so I cannot answer  why. I'm curious about creating output in functions, never though about it that way before your functionals are interesting.   Shiny Server is one server process that can serve many users. Data in the server code block is private to one session. You don't want your functions instantiated by every user of the app, so they should be outside server block, same with any static data (as your your tibbles). If you want to generate outputs dynamically best is to use uioutput() where you can return a taglist() of many things.